# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i have a problem when updating the database

error: **Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.**

controller:

```
 public function actualizar(Request $request){
    
    $nuevoIngreso = \App\Models\Servicio::all();
    $nuevoIngreso->costo = $request->costo;
    $nuevoIngreso->duracion = $request->duracion;
    $nuevoIngreso->mantenimiento = $request->mantenimiento;
    $nuevoIngreso->save();
    return redirect('servicios')->with('mensaje', 'Ficha Actualizada.');

}
```

blade.php

```
         <form method="POST" action="{{ route('actualizar') }}">
                {{method_field('PUT')}}
@csrf

                    @foreach ($servicios as $costo)
<h1 class="text-center text-primary">  {{$costo->tipo}} </h1>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Costo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->costo}}">
                
                    </div>
                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Duración</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->duracion}}" id="example-text-input">
                    </div>
                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Mantenimiento</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->mantenimiento}}" id="example-text-input">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 <hr>
               @endforeach

               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right" float-rightdata-toggle="sweet-alert" data-sweet-alert="success">SAVE</button>
                </form>
```

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is clear.you are calling static method `all()`.So it should be

```
  $nuevoIngreso =new \App\Models\Servicio();
    $nuevoIngreso->costo = $request->costo;
    $nuevoIngreso->duracion = $request->duracion;
    $nuevoIngreso->mantenimiento = $request->mantenimiento;
    $nuevoIngreso->save();
```

So if you are thinking to update particular record then find by id or any column

```
 $nuevoIngreso =new \App\Models\Servicio::find($id);
        $nuevoIngreso->costo = $request->costo;
        $nuevoIngreso->duracion = $request->duracion;
        $nuevoIngreso->mantenimiento = $request->mantenimiento;
        $nuevoIngreso->save();
```

**Updated**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('actualizar') }}">
    {{method_field('PUT')}}
    @csrf

    @foreach ($servicios as $key=>$costo)
        <h1 class="text-center text-primary">  {{$costo->tipo}} </h1>
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="{{$costo->id}}" name="service[{{$key}}][id]">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Costo</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->costo}}" name="service[{{$key}}][costo]">

            </div>
            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Duración</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->duracion}}" id="example-text-input" name="service[{{$key}}][duracion]">
            </div>
            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Mantenimiento</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$costo->mantenimiento}}" id="example-text-input" name="service[{{$key}}][mantenimiento]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right" float-rightdata-toggle="sweet-alert" data-sweet-alert="success">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Then in controller

```
foreach($request->service as $key=>$value){

 $nuevoIngreso =new \App\Models\Servicio::find($value['id']);
 if($nuevoIngreso){
 $nuevoIngreso->costo = $value['costo'];
 $nuevoIngreso->duracion = $value['duracion'];
 $nuevoIngreso->mantenimiento = $value['mantenimiento'];
 $nuevoIngreso->save();
 }
}
```

Comment: if I don't have column ID I can't update?

Comment: @jererosas .. if you are creating new Servicio then you can use first one or else finding by id or you have to mention which coumn base you need to save data.can you tell me what exactly you wants to do in that method

Comment: sure, I need to update existing records, not create new Servicio

Comment: is it all records or particular.if particular what condition do you need to check

Comment: in form keep hidden id field for each row

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="{{$costo->id}}">  so I can hide the id?

Comment: you forgot name attribute in all input . add name="service[]['id']"  .give each input name or else it wont work

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/b0CvRMR.png with new it doesn't work

Comment: what error .also before loop try to dd($request->all()) and post it

Comment: can you dd($request->all())

Comment: It has worked, thank you, I learned a lot